# Adding files to form in Django makes editing form behave differently - why?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple model I can edit by using another simple form - and that works well:

when I click on "edit", it correctly shows existing fields in an editing form;

Everything changes when I add `files=request.FILES` to my view - then it somehow forgets existing data and I'm left with clear form and info "This field is required" on required fields (even though they are filled because this item exists).

Interestingly, it only remembers the image that was uploaded earlier.

views.py

```py
def add_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        news = NewsModel(author=request.user)
        form = AddNewsForm(instance=news, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES) #this works fine
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Added a news!')
            return redirect('main:news')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "You didn't fill the form, try again")
    else:
        form = AddNewsForm()        
    return render(request, 'news/add_news.html', {'form':form})

def edit_news(request, id):
    news = get_object_or_404(NewsModel, id=id)
    form = AddNewsForm(request.POST or None, instance=news, files=request.FILES) #here is the problem

    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Changed a news.')
    return render(request, 'news/add_news.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```py
    re_path(r'^news/new/$', views.add_news, {}, 'news_new'),
    re_path(r'^news/edit_(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.edit_news, {}, 'news_edit'),
```

forms.py

```py
class AddNewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

template

```html
<h1> Add/change a news</h1>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{form}}
    {% csrf_token %}
<h2> <input type="submit" value="Go!"/> </h2>
</form>
```

Without that one `files=request.FILES` in edit_news, everything works. What's going on?

Comment: Maybe you can solve it by setting the past values as default values for edit form. Thanks to this, you should get your edit from already filled with the values previously saved.